# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-12-01 17:00:00+00:00'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have timestamp in my data of this format 2021-12-01 19:00:00+00:00 ,

My data looks like this  [image]

I am applying isolation forest to label the data and i tried the code but got error ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-12-01 17:00:00+00:00'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert `timestamp` column as int:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype('datetime64').astype(int)
```

Comment: Now i got this error raise TypeError(f"cannot astype a datetimelike from [{arr.dtype}] to [{dtype}]")
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? That worked for me.

Comment: version 1.2.4 and which version you are using ?

Comment: I actually got a _warning_ with this : `FutureWarning: casting datetime64[ns] values to int64 with .astype(...) is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use .view(...) instead.`

Answer (score 3):

Adding `parse_dates=[<columns>]` to `pd.read_csv` will cause Pandas to automatically convert strings that look like dates to actual datetime objects:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/labeling/fCCC.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype('int')
```